# Inject Style Declarations Using Hostbinding in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-hostbinding

Do you guys know how I can batch inject style declarations in a component using the @HostBinding decorator?
What I am trying is:

```
@HostBinding('style')
get style(): CSSStyleDeclaration {
  return {
    background: 'red',
    color: 'lime'
  } as CSSStyleDeclaration;
}
```

In my understanding this should inject the background and color style to the component, but it does not...

I can control individual style declarations like this:

```
@HostBinding('style.background') private background = 'red';
```

but I would like to do it for all of them, please help :P

this is the full code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello world!</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  // This works
  @HostBinding('style.color') private color = 'lime';

  /* This does not work
  @HostBinding('style')
  get style(): CSSStyleDeclaration {
    return {
      background: 'red'
    } as CSSStyleDeclaration;
  }
  */

  constructor() {}
}
```

and a working plunker: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/CVglAPAMIsdQjsqHU4Fb?p=preview

Comment: What styles did you try to inject? What does "does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: nothing happens, no erors and the styles(background and color) do not get applied. I think that my syntax might be wrong or the style attribute might not be available for binding to using the HostBinding decorator.

Comment: Please add the CSS style you try to apply and the HTML where you want it applied (minimal example that allows to reproduce).

Comment: sorry about that I am not that used to stackoverflow, I added all the code and a working plunker example, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Plunker is very helpful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to pass the same value you would add to an element like `<div style="...">` and [sanitize](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) the styles

```
  @HostBinding('style')
  get myStyle(): SafeStyle {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('background: red; display: block;');
  }

  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {}
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-hostbinding-demo)

Comment: The plunker says  /* this does not work */, any update

Comment: Copying to a new Plunker would probably do to get the Angular version updated. I'll have a look when I have a bit of time (no guarantees)

Comment: @BenTaliadoros Demo was broken. Fixed it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, here you go - https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-hostbinding-demo

Comment: How can you set multiple definitions for the same style, e.g. `cursor: grab; cursor: -webkit-grab`

Comment: I don't think you can. Better to set/clear a class and use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that can cover if you want to pass multiple css styles as string or as object with cammelCase conventions:

**Parent HTML**

```
<app-button [style]="styleFromParent">Some button</app-button>
```

Parent component has `styleFromParent` property and it has simulation if that property is changed at some point:

**Parent Component TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-site-panel',
  templateUrl: './site-panel.component.html',
})
export class SitePanelComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _detectChanges: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  styleFromParent = { marginTop: '10px', marginLeft: '50px' };

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.styleFromParent = { marginTop: '20px', marginLeft: '1px' };

      this._detectChanges.detectChanges();
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

**Child HTML**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**Child Component TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeStyle } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('style') baseStyle: SafeStyle;

  @Input()
  set style(style: string | object) {
    let mappedStyles = style as string;

    if (typeof style === 'object') {
      mappedStyles = Object.entries(style).reduce((styleString, [propName, propValue]) => {
        propName = propName.replace(/([A-Z])/g, matches => `-${matches[0].toLowerCase()}`);
        return `${styleString}${propName}:${propValue};`;
      }, '');

      this.baseStyle = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(mappedStyles);
    } else if (typeof style === 'string') {
      this.baseStyle = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(mappedStyles);
    }
  }

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Above you can see that `baseStyle` has `HostBinding` to `style` component binding.
When `style` input is passed setter will triger, check if string or object is passed, parse it to string and sanitize that css and assign it to `baseStyle` thus host style will change.