# Angular 7 CSS not working while using reusable component

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular7

*I am fairly new to Angular and came from React.js background.*

I have made a simple grid component like below:

`grid.component.js`

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid',
  template: `
    <div [ngStyle]="styles()" [ngClass]="passClass">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    div {
      display: flex;
    }
  `]
})
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() direction: string;
  @Input() justify: string;
  @Input() align: string;
  @Input() width: string;
  @Input() passClass: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  styles() {
    return {
      'flex-direction': this.direction || 'row',
      'justify-content': this.justify || 'flex-start',
      'align-items': this.align || 'flex-start',
      ...(this.width && { width: this.width })
    };
  }
}
```

And I want to use it in other components like below:
`aboutus.component.html`

```html
<app-grid passClass="about-us page-container">
  <app-grid direction="column" passClass="left">
    <div class="title blue bold">
      An open community For Everyone
    </div>
    <div class="large-desc grey">
      This conference is brought to you by
      the Go Language Community in
      India together with the Emerging
      Technology Trust (ETT). ETT is a non-
      profit organization, established to
      organize and conduct technology
      conferences in India. It’s current
      portfolio includes
    </div>
  </app-grid>
</app-grid>
```

`aboutus.component.sass`

```css
.about-us
  position: relative
  .left
    width: 50%
    &:after
      bottom: 0
      right: 0
      z-index: 0
      margin-right: -5vw
      position: absolute
      content: url(../../assets/images/footer.svg)
```

But, what happens is the CSS attached with the second component will not work.

I know a little bit about CSS isolation but could not understand if it affects here.

P.S.: Please feel free to provide feedback to things outside of scope this question as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to pass CSS classes as variables in your template. So if your expectation in `aboutus.component.html` was to be able to pass the `left` CSS class as a variable in your template, that will not work.

There are a few things I can point out that will hopefully help:

1. If you want to modify a CSS class that is internal to a component from outside that component, one option is to use [ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).
2. In your particular case, I don't think `ng-deep` is necessary. I'd suggest to drop the `div` element within the `app-grid` component and instead apply the styles to the host element using `@HostBinding` decorator. With that approach you can drop the `passCss` altogether because now wherever you use your`app-grid` component you can style that component in CSS using the `app-grid` selector.

   grid.component.ts:

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit, Input, HostBinding, SafeStyle } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-grid',
     template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
     styles: [`
       :host {
         display: flex;
       }
     `]
   })
   export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
     @Input() direction: string;
     @Input() justify: string;
     @Input() align: string;
     @Input() width: string;

     constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) { }

     ngOnInit() {
     }

     @HostBinding('style')
     styles(): SafeStyle {
       const styles = `
         flex-direction: ${this.direction || 'row'};
         justify-content: ${this.justify || 'flex-start'};
         align-items: ${this.align || 'flex-start'};
      `;
       return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(styles);
     }
   }
   ```

   aboutus.component.sass:

   ```
     app-grid {
       // You can style the host element of a component
       // just like any native HTML element and without
       // needing to use `ng-deep`
     }
   ```
3. You may also want to look into [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Basic_usage). Custom CSS properties are not shielded by view-encapsulation. This gives you the ability to create a CSS API for a component, if you will, and those properties can be used anywhere within a component.

   aboutus.component.sass

   ```
   app-grid {
     --image: url(../../assets/images/footer.svg)
   }
   ```

   grid.component.sass

   ```
   div {
     content: var(--image);
   }
   ```

Comment: Your solution seems to be the perfect one. But, there is some issue with the code you mentioned. `@HostBinding('style') styles()` is not working and I tried binding to `@HostBinding('attr.style')` then it was said to be unsafe. I had to do a single style binding like `@HostBinding('style.flex-direction')`. Can you please update that and I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Oh right, you have to use the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustStyle) as  shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46151691/3634032). I will amend my answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want style some element in other component use `:host` and `/deep/` modifiers(deprecated - [Alternative to /deep/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708972/alternative-to-deep)). More about this feature you can read in [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors)

In your case this should work:

```css
:host /deep/ {
    .left {
        width: 50%
        &:after {
          bottom: 0
          right: 0
          z-index: 0
          margin-right: -5vw
          position: absolute
          content: url(../../assets/images/footer.svg)
       }
    }
}
```

You can also disable encapsulation for this component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid',
  template: `
    <div [ngStyle]="styles()" [ngClass]="passClass">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    div {
      display: flex;
    }
  `],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: Thanks, In the aboutus component css?

Comment: Isn't /deep/ deprecated in angular 7?

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately I don't know any alternative

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708972/alternative-to-deep - some more informations about this deprecation in Angular

Comment: I am skeptical about using `ViewEncapsulation.None` I am not sure if It can affect other things. Like if I have `div` selector in another component, I guess it will be affected by that right?