# Setting multiple inline style properties with @HostBinding

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

This works:

```
  @HostBinding('style.width') get w() {
    return this.width ? this.width : '';
  }
  @HostBinding('style.height') get h() {
    return this.height ? this.height : '';
  }
```

Is there a way to do this with a single `@HostBinding`?

Comment: This has already been addressed here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150788/inject-style-declarations-using-hostbinding-in-angular&ved=2ahUKEwiA97Ckkf7kAhVc7HMBHVnWAWMQjjgwAHoECAIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3GeQNFQD6KaUPtncGqoCt3

Comment: Ah - So we need to use the Sanitizer - Good tip - Thanks!